# How can I solve this Java inheritance exercise?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm a beginner. Sorry for that..

I'm wracking my brain in order to solve this excercise.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much

...........................................................................

Define two classes,in Java, called MyBaseClass and MyDerivedClass.

The former class declares a protected and abstract method called meth(), which has non parameters and which returns an integer value.

The latter class extends the first one and implements the inherited method by returning the value 5.

.......................................................

My implementation is (I know it's wrong but sorry I don't know why..):

```
public MyBaseClass {

    protected abstract meth();
    return ();
}

public MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {

 meth();
 return (5);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a big lack of understanding of what a class can contain and how OOP works in general. What you have inside a class are methods and variables, not statements of code.

Clearly `meth();` is a statement, a call to a function indeed. While what you are looking for is to implement the abstract method:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
 protected abstract int meth();
}

public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {
 protected int meth { return 5; }
}
```

Look: every class encloses with `{ }` a body that contains a list of methods that are defined by a signature (eg. `protected int meth()`) and a body too (unless `abstract`). Variables are allowed too.

But IMHO you should concentrate more on learning OOP basics and programming basics before digging into inheritance.. and always remember: in a full object-oriented programming language (like Java), statements cannot reside outside method bodies.

Comment: protected abstract meth();  should be protected abstract int meth();

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is lacking basic principles in Java. Maybe you should study first how to declare a method/class in Java. However here is the correct solution:

The abstract class:

```
public abstract MyBaseClass {
    protected abstract int meth();
}
```

The descendant class:

```
public MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass {
    @Override
    protected int meth() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should declare MyBaseClass abstract so it cannot be directly instantiated surely? It has no use as an Object.

Comment: Thanks . First I forgot the variable type int, secondly I just made a big mistake when trying to override the meth method. Is  @Override
compulsory?

Comment: No it is not, it is a static check added to the normal ones that simply helps you developing (and avoiding typos)

Comment: @Override is not necessary but it helps while developing to avoid typos or things like that.

Comment: @Greenhouse Gases yes maybe, but I followed his description.

Comment: @Roflcoptr fair enough! I suppose that is a bit far along for a beginner but I just felt it was worth mentioning in the interest of writing good code!

Comment: @Greenhouse Gases.. yes that's true, so I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass{

protected abstract int meth();


}

public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass{

protected int meth(){
return 5;
}

}
```

Comment: So your code is the right one? MyBaseClass should be declared abstract so that the method meth() can be called from inside MyDerivedClass..is it correct? So you're saying that the overriding operation might not be performed ..correct?

Comment: Reply 1/2: Basically if something is abstract it cannot be directly used, so in this case you cannot create an object of type MyBaseClass because it is abstract. You can however create an object of MyDerivedClass because it is not abstract. It also provides an implementation for the meth() method, so that method can be called on a MyDerivedClass object.

Comment: Reply 2/2: You use @Override in derived classes if the base class has implemented a method of the same signature (ie. meth()) and you want to tell the compiler to use the meth() implementation in the derived class, not the super class meth() which it inherits as a direct subclass.

Comment: What you will learn is that with OOP you can take advantage of polymorphism which if you don't know, is a fancy way of using any object of a derived class (of the base class) in places where the program expects an object of the base class type. This concept may be too advanced for when just starting to learn, but you will see it crop up soon enough!

Comment: Note: In Reply 1/2 - You can create an object of MyBaseClass but you cannot instantiate it is what I meant. So basically you could do:
   
    MyBaseClass mbc = new MyDerivedClass();

You can't do this though:

    MyBaseClass mbc = new MyBaseClass(); 

this follows the idea of polymorphism.